# polyline is not working for following cordinates in leaflet

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, polyline

[image]

Please look at above screen shot I have to draw polyline from one point to another but on map it show like this, **staring point** lat : 35.3560 lng :  119.5521 **ending point**  lat :-41.789233 lng :-73.139059

It seem that the map is working in 2 parts.

Comment: Do you want a straight line between the start and end point? Or is something wrong with the yellow line?

Comment: Yes I want straight line between tow points.